# Cross-platform mobile framework that can access call logs

Tags: android, blackberry, mobile, frameworks, cross-platform

I've come across a few suggestions of "develop-once, deploy anywhere" mobile frameworks from other SO questions:

http://www.mosync.com
http://rhomobile.com
http://phonegap.com

I was wondering if there are other alternatives to these mobile frameworks. None of them have the ability to access call logs or hook into a phone's call events (I realize those aren't possible on iPhone).

Comment: This is typical smartphone feature. You're unlikely to find something that work on the huge number of feature phone out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the ability you want is pretty specific to the device, so it is unlikely anyone will come up with a framework in the near future that supports it.

That said, PhoneGap supports adding any native code you desire, so you could do the bulk of the app in it and then add native code for the bits that are not supported.  It's a lot easier than creating apps from scratch for each platform.

Comment: I don't get your answer. Isn't that the point of a framework like this - to wrap up the device specific functionality into a common interface?

Comment: The idea of a framework is to wrap up the common functionality into a common interface...

Comment: Right, most smartphones have a specific API for accessing the call logs. A common interface through a framework is what I'm after.

Comment: No one's done that yet, but you could request it or do it yourself on PhoneGap.

Answer (score 2):

There's [Appcelerator Titanium Mobile](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile/) for Android/iPhone, but I don't know if it can do what you're looking for, either.

Answer (score 0):

The Qt Mobility project is the only one with such functionality i think but i am not sure, more info at http://labs.trolltech.com/page/Projects/QtMobility

more info:
http://qt.nokia.com/developer/new-qt-apis

platforms supported:
http://qt.nokia.com/doc/qtmobility-1.0-tp/index.html#platform-compatability